# Manually add jquery and jquery-ui to grails project

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grails

I've been coding in grails now for a couple months. They get added to the page through the main.gsp file with the following:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery"/>
<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
```

The jquery and jquery-ui plugins have been working fine for dialogs, sorting, etc, but I want to add the tabs widget to my pages now and the versions of jquery and jquery-ui that come with the plugins framework don't seem to work with them. When I add the sources directly to a page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

everything works fine. So now I'm thinking of dumping the plugins entirely and just adding the libs in manually.

What is the best way to go about doing this? I could put them in the /js directory and modify ApplicationResources.groovy to reference them, but a co-worker mentioned he preferred adding them to the grails.resources.modules section of Config.groovy. I would like to know what the best way to accomplish this would be.

I also have the following in Config.groovy:

```
grails.resources.modules = {

overrides {
    'jquery-theme' {
        resource id: 'theme', url: '/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css'
    }
}
```

Do I need to move this somewhere else or change it if I remove the plugins and manage the libs myself?

Answer (score 8):

The two options are valid. You can work with the `Config.groovy` or `ApplicationResources.groovy`.

Before removing the plugins I suggest you to check if the version that you need exists. The plugin portal of grails.org will show you only the latest version. I tried here and `:jquery:1.9.1` exists but `:jquery-ui:1.10` not.

### Manually declare resources

So, if you need, you can declare your resources for JQuery and JQuery UI. Just remove the plugins and the overrides, and add your configs. The files must go in js and/or css folders.

You can also check the environment and change to the minified version if needed. Example:

```
//use the minified version in production
def minified = GrailsUtil.isDevelopmentEnv() ? "" : ".min"

modules = {
  jquery {
    resource url: "/js/jquery-1.9.1${minified}.js"
  }
  'jquery-ui' {
    resource url: "/js/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui${minified}.js"
    resource url: "/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom${minified}.css"
  }
}
```

Comment: I put it to the tribunal that this answer be accepted.

Comment: @Michels can you please share the location where to place the jquery.js file? I removed the plugin and then added the above lines but my jquery is not loading.